# How do I change background color of layout of list-view item using array-adapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have Listview, ArrayAdapter and Layout for ArrayAdapter as ItemView.

Now, I have managed to change the background color of selected/clicked item's layout.

But how can I change the background color to the original when another item is selected?

Code Sample :

```
Listview listview;
int PREVIOUSLY_SELECTED_ID = -1;

        if (arrayList != null) {
        Collections.sort(arrayList);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList){
            @NonNull
            @Override public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, @NonNull final ViewGroup parent) {

                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();

                // This is the Layout File "listitem_layout.xml" i am inflating to arrayadapter.
                @SuppressLint({"ViewHolder", "InflateParams"}) final View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_layout, null, true);

                // This is the RelativeLayout in "listitem_layout.xml".
                final RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relativelayout_selected_item);

                // This is onClick event of "relativelayout".
                relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override public void onClick(View v) {

                        if (PREVIOUSLY_SELECTED_ID != position)
                        {
                            // Here, i am changing background color of relativelayout when item is clicked.
                            v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.tomatoLight);
                            if(PREVIOUSLY_SELECTED_ID != -1)
                            {
                                // Here, i want to change Previously Selected Item's Background Color to it's original(Which is 'Orange'). 
                                listView.getAdapter().getView(position,convertView,parent).setBackgroundResource(R.color.orange);
                            }
                            PREVIOUSLY_SELECTED_ID = position;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.orange);
                        }
                });

                return view;
            }
        };
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
 }
```

Comment: have you added any flag for detecting selected items?

Comment: Yes "SELECTED_ID" is int flag to remember last selected id.

Comment: How much data on your arrayList?

Comment: You need set a flag for detecting selected items on your data list.

Comment: single "SELECTED_ID" is not enough there should be array of those ids, In your array adapter if(SELECTED_ID[current]==selected)then color_selected else color_not_selected

Comment: Let me be clear, "SELECTED_ID" is int flag which stores current selected item's id AND "position" is current position id.

Comment: Then how can you get the previously selected items?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [getChildAt()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt%28int%29) method of Listview to get the view and then change the color.

```
     if (SELECTED_ID != -1) {
        View view1 = listView.getChildAt(SELECTED_ID -
                                  listView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
                            // Here, i want to change Previously Selected Item's Background Color to it's original(Which is 'Orange').
                            view1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Orange);

                        }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It did work for me, just replace this if block rest will be same and please tell what else is doing, it is supposed to remain selected if both previous and selected positions are same, right? then else should also change to tomatoLight.

Answer (score 0):

You can just keep track of your last clicked item then notify the adapter so that it'll set the backgrounds accordingly

**Update**
Use an `OnItemClickListener` to catch the click instead of using the view itself

```
Listview listview;
int selectedPosition = -1;
if (arrayList != null) {
    Collections.sort(arrayList);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList) {
        @NonNull
        @Override 
        public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, @NonNull final ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
            @SuppressLint({"ViewHolder", "InflateParams"}) 
            final View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_layout, null, true);
            final RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relativelayout_selected_item);

            // if the views that is currently being created is the same is the one clicked before notifying the adapter then change it's color
            if (selectedPosition == position) {
                relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.tomatoLight);
            } else {
                relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.orange);
            }

            return view;
        }
    };
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemclickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int position, long id) {
                selectedPosition = position;
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: "v" is View of onClick(View v) so it wont work outside of onClick() event. think again!

Comment: Yes I updated my answer.. it's the `relativeLayout` view that should be used outside the `onClick`

Comment: Yes, but when click on item, i want to change background color to "tomatolight" AND when i click on another item, the previous item's background change to "orange"(it's original color).

Comment: The idea is to have `SELECTED_ID` contain the currently selected item.. when you notify the adapter using `notifyDataSetChanged` only the clicked item will be tomatolight all the others will be orange.. did you try the code I provided on your application?

Comment: And it wont work because you are changing SELECTED_ID before comparing it with current position.

Comment: i changed name so you can understand.

Comment: I updated my answer.. but that's the idea.. it is not to keep track of the previously selected item but the currently selected one.. all the other item will have original background after notfiying the adapter since their position is different from `SELECTED_ID`

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged   won't work because arrayList which is passed to adapter is not changed.

Comment: listView.setOnItemclickListener() wont work here, i've tried

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged` will force the adapter to refresh views even if the data itself hasn't changed

Comment: you can use either `setOnItemClickListerner` on a click listener on the view itself.. the idea is to update the adapter to force only the selected item to change background color

Comment: i already solved this problem earlier by creating pojo of data and selected_id in arraylist then notifyDataSetChanged started working in my case.

Comment: Sorry, but not working in mine. i tried your new code too.

Comment: Could you describe what happens when you used that code.. may be I'll be able to find another way

Comment: Well every item which i clicked gets change there background.

Comment: I updated my answer.. it may be related to the way you handle the view inside the `getView` of you adapter

Answer (score 0):

@ColdFire is right in that you have to **override** the default behavior of ArrayAdapter's `getView` method. I believe just using ListView's `getChild` method just returns a view with a difference reference. That's why nothing happens when you try to modify it by calling `setBackgroundColor` (you're setting the background color of a difference list item view.

If you want other items color to change when you click another item, you'll need to remember more than just one value. e.g.: Perhaps you'd want to use another variable in addition to `selectedPosition`, say `previousPosition`, and keep track on the values of these variables when changes occur. These are just two variables which means you can only remember two things at a time. Perhaps use a `List<Integer>` or an `int[]` array and add or remove values as the user selects and deselects items in the list.